# AWS: Find IP address of all connections to RDS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Is there a way to find the IP addresses of all connections to AWS RDS instances.

Answer (score 4):

You can get connected Host IP from `information_schema` using MySQL Query.

```
 select host from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

Because in basic monitoring only these metrics are available.

For Monitoring, choose the option for how you want to view your metrics from these:

**CloudWatch:**

> Shows a summary of DB instance metrics available from Amazon
>   CloudWatch. Each metric includes a graph showing the metric monitored
>   over a specific time span.

**Enhanced monitoring:**

> Shows a summary of OS metrics available for a DB instance with
>   Enhanced Monitoring enabled. Each metric includes a graph showing the
>   metric monitored over a specific time span.

**OS Process list:**

> Shows details for each process running in the selected instance.

So the option that can help you in this regards is Performance Insights.

**Performance Insights:**

If you are interested in detail matrics like HOST IPs, the number of connections, Slow queries and many more which can eliminate the need of DBA I believe as very good experience with [Using Amazon RDS Performance Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.html)

Top activity can list any of the dimensions indicated at the top of the list. For Aurora PostgreSQL, Performance Insights currently supports listing top SQL, waits, hosts, and users.

[image]

[analyzing-amazon-rds-database-workload-with-performance-insights](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/analyzing-amazon-rds-database-workload-with-performance-insights/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB:

```
select id, user, host, db, command, time, state, info, progress from information_schema.processlist;
```

Other options specific to AWS.

- Turn on VPC Flowlogs , then use loginishgts to query historical
  traffic to the instances.
- Inspect the security group of the RDS, it may list the client(s) which is allowed to connect to it.
- Turn on the general query log https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MariaDB.html